# Angular 4 delay declare google in component till async defer js is ready

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

So in my index.html file I have

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=##MYKEY##'></script>
```

and in my app.component.ts file

```
declare var google: any;
@Component({
    ....
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ....
    map;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
        });
    }
}
```

And the map gets loaded just fine.

However, when I add **async defer** attributes to script file,

```
<script async defer src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=##MYKEY##'></script>
```

I get a `ReferenceError: google is not defined`, I assume that it is due to googleapi javascript not ready.

How to delay declaration `google` in component and make sure that `google` is ready?

Answer (score 0):

I's not the *declaration* of google that is causing the issue (that declaration is just for typescript), but the call to

```
new google.maps
```

before the api is loaded

You can either remove the async keyword (simplest, bu you app might be slightly slower)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#sync

Or pass a callback to the script

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=methodToCall">
```

From that method, you could trigger an event and catch that event in your component, and create the map afterwards